# Dyanmic Query Keys with React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have this situation where I have to generate query keys to be used by react query.

```
const datesToRequest = ['2023-11-01', '2023-11-02', '2023-11-03']
```

//`Above is actually dynamically generated. For the ease of explaining I've hard coded it.`

```
const vehiclesQuery = (dates: string[]) => useQuery({ 
   queryKey: ['dates', ...datesToRequest], 
   queryFn: () => fetchVehiclesByDate(dates) })

const vehicles = vehiclesQuery(datesToRequest)
```

`fetchVehiclesByDate` will call to the server and return some data. However, the `fetchVehiclesByDate` function is not seems to be getting called.

It works only when I have the query key is hard coded like below:

```
useQuery({ 
    queryKey: ['2023-11-01'], 
    queryFn: () => fetchVehiclesByDate(['2023-11-01']) })
```

Any idea on how to get this working for my case?